# Error 400 bad request JqGrid

Tags: java, jquery, spring, jakarta-ee, jqgrid

I try to "POST" data, but when i'm doing it, i'm getting ERROR 400. I have the same issue with "UPDATE" data. I have no idea how to solve this problem.

This is my jqgrid code:
    $(function() {

```
    $.extend($.jgrid.defaults, {
        datatype: 'json',
        jsonReader : {
            repeatitems:false,
            total: function(result) {
                //Total number of pages
                return Math.ceil(result.total / result.max);
            },
            records: function(result) {
                //Total number of records
                return result.total;
            }
        },
        prmNames: {
            rows: 'max', 
            search: null
        },
        height: 'auto',
        viewrecords: true,
        rowList: [10, 20, 50, 100],
        altRows: true,
        loadError: function(xhr, status, error) {
            alert(error);
        }
    });

    $.extend($.jgrid.edit, {
        closeAfterEdit: true,
        closeAfterAdd: true,
        ajaxEditOptions: {
            contentType: "application/json"
        },
        mtype: 'PUT',
        serializeEditData: function(data) {
            delete data.oper;
            return JSON.stringify(data);
        }
    });
    $.extend($.jgrid.del, {
        mtype: 'DELETE',
        serializeDelData: function() {
            return "";
        }
    });

    var editOptions = {
        onclickSubmit: function(params, postdata) {
            params.url = URL + '/' + postdata.id;
        }
    };
    var addOptions = {
        mtype: "POST"
    };
    var delOptions = {
        onclickSubmit: function(params, postdata) {
            params.url = URL + '/' + postdata;
        }
    };

    var URL = 'rest/poll';
    var options = {
        url: URL,
        editurl: URL,
        colModel:[
        {
            name:'id', 
            label: 'ID',
            formatter:'integer',
            width: 40,
            editable: true,
            editoptions: {
                disabled: true, 
                size:5
            }
        },
        {
            name: 'categories.name', 
            index: 'categories', 
            label: 'Category',
            editable: true, 
            edittype: "select",
            viewrecords:true,

            editoptions: {
                dataUrl:"rest/category/list.do", 
                buildSelect: function (list) 
                { 
                    var data = jQuery.parseJSON(list); 
                    var s = '<select>'; 
                    for (var i = 0; i < data.locationList.length; i++) {
                        s += '<option value="' + data.locationList[i] + '">' + data.locationList[i].name + '</option>'; 
                    } 
                    return s + "</select>"; 
                } 
            } 
        },
        {
            name:'name',
            label: 'Name',
            width: 300,
            editable: true,
            editrules: {
                required: true
            }
        },

        {
            name: 'MyLink',
            formatter: myLinkFormatter
        }

        ],
        caption: "Polls",
        pager : '#pager',
        height: 'auto',
        ondblClickRow: function(id) {
            jQuery(this).jqGrid('editGridRow', id, editOptions);
        }
    };

    $("#grid")
    .jqGrid(options)
    .navGrid('#pager',
    {}, //options
        editOptions,
        addOptions,
        delOptions,
        {} // search options
        );

});

function myLinkFormatter (cellvalue, options, rowObjcet) {
    return '<a href = "/Polls_V2/options?categoryId=' + options.rowId + '">Answers</a>';
}
```

And this my controller code :

```
 @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ResponseEntity<String> createCategory(HttpServletRequest request, @RequestBody Polls polls) {
        pollsService.add(polls);

        URI uri = new UriTemplate("{requestUrl}/{username}").expand(request.getRequestURL().toString(), polls.getId());
        final HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.put("Location", Collections.singletonList(uri.toASCIIString()));
        return new ResponseEntity<String>(headers, HttpStatus.CREATED);
    }
```

Comment: I got the same error as you got when edit item. Could you share how you solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not too familiar with Java, but I'd run an app like [firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) or [fiddler web debugger](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/), and inspect the ajax request too see if its building up correctly (as error 400 is bad request related)

I'n the past I've build up my JqGrid add/edit/delete calls like this [really really old jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Yenros/bbPeP/) I created... but that did work for me.

```
DataGrid.navGrid('#pager', { edit: true, add: true, del: true, search: true },
           {                   
                url: this.urlEdit, ...
            },
            {                   
                url: this.urlAdd,  ...
            },
            {                   
                url: this.urlDelete, ...
            }
        );
```

.. also, i't looks like the controller code you supplied is the code for the get data call for the grid... Which isn't relevant to your question I'm guessing. (e.g. are you trying to perform a post to a  "RequestMethod.GET" action). Can you please supply the code for the method that handles the POST?